# Storing value in javascript vars

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

This might be a lame question, but for me as a javascript newbie it's really a mystery.
Here is a short sample of my code that handles geolocation:

```
  if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            var latitude, longitude;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function(position) {
                        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                        // Here I get user's coordinates
                        alert("Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude : " + longitude);

                    },
                    function() {
                        alert("Geo Location not supported");
                    }
            );
            // Here I don't get anything
            alert("Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude : " + longitude);
            new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude ,longitude)
            }, this.getCallback());
        }
        else {
            error("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
```

As I've already mentioned in the comments - I the first case, I get coordinates, but in the second one, the values of those vars are `undefined` and thus I can't get the location on the map... What may cause this and how to pass those values to the Geocoder ?

Comment: You're aware that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is executed asynchronously?

Comment: Well this may explain a lot...but still the problem remains, as I'd need to get those values to the Geocoder

Comment: @Teemu unlikely...he states in his post that he is a JS noob.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Geolocation wait until success before return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166039/js-geolocation-wait-until-success-before-return-value)

Comment: @FrankTudor Haha... Being a newbie shouldn't prevent anybody to read some documentation of the API one is going to use ; ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how asynchronous requests work.  You have to wait till the request completes and then execute the next block of code as callback to the success function.  Executing it all in line will cause problems as you are experiencing.

```
function(position) {
  latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  // Here I get user's coordinates
  alert("Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude : " + longitude);

  new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude ,longitude)
  }, this.getCallback());
}
```

note: you'll probably need to change the context of `this`, for `this.callback`

Comment: This won't help either... I've already tried it and it fails, nevertheless the rest of the code is correct for sure, because if I put it somewhere else with predefined coordinates, it works well

Comment: TypeError: this.getCallback is not a function.  I've got it defined as  `getCallback: function() {
        //some code
    },`

Comment: right, I told you in my post that would likely be an issue.  you have to circumvent that reference to `this` because of where you are using `this`.  One way is define `this` as it's own variable; `var self = this`, and then doing `self.getCallBack`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't execute `getCallback`, you just pass the reference to it